# Vue-cli production build - browser cache problem?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, webpack, caching, vue-cli

We are building e-commerce, we're using vue on front, and we decided it's the best to follow vue team recommendations, and start new project with vue-cli.

Our problem appears when we are trying to deliver new version to our clients. We are building new application, new files in dist/ folder appears, with new hashes in the name... aaanddd clients still has old version.

That's actually the weirdest part, that browser is somehow caching our code, despite of new hashes O.o

Do anybody had similar problem? And any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Trace the links for js files in main html file - the hash-es are updated? The links for you clients also have updated hashes?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, it updates to new version only when you reload the browser instead of refresh, or close current tab and open new browser tab.

Comment: does anyone have solution to this?

Comment: Is your apps configured as PWAs? I'd bet this is a problem related to service worker offline caching

Comment: Anyway, if you're having problem with this, to see if the problem is with the serviceworker go to (chrome) devtools > Application > Service Workers > [ ] Bypass for network, check that box, make a deploy and reload the page, this should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is nothing to with service worker/PWA, the solution could be implemented by returning the front end version by letting the server return the current version of the Vue App everytime.

`axiosConfig.js`

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (resp) => {
    let fe_version = resp.headers['fe-version'] || 'default'
    if(fe_version !== localStorage.getItem('fe-version') && resp.config.method == 'get'){
      localStorage.setItem('fe-version', fe_version)
      window.location.reload() // For new version, simply reload on any get
    }
    return Promise.resolve(resp)
  },
)
```

Full Article here: https://blog.francium.tech/vue-js-cache-not-getting-cleared-in-production-on-deploy-656fcc5a85fe

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem could be that the browser is caching the `index.html` file.

Try to disable cache for `index.html` like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Or if you are using a .htaccess file, add this code to the bottom of the file:

```
<Files index.html>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</Files>
```